# Javascript : Change the function of the browser's back button

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make the user's back button on their browser, call a javascript function instead of going back a page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I stop the browser back button using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't override the behaviour that if a user follows a link to your page, clicking Back will take them off it again.

But you can make JavaScript actions on your page add entries into the history as though they were clicks to new pages, and control what happens with Back and Forward in the context of those clicks.

There are JavaScript libraries to help with this, with [Really Simple History](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) being a popular example.

Answer (score 29):

yes, you can. Use this js:

```
(function(window, location) {
    history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname+"#!/stealingyourhistory");
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.pathname);

    window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
      if(location.hash === "#!/stealingyourhistory") {
            history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname);
            setTimeout(function(){
              location.replace("http://www.programadoresweb.net/");
            },0);
      }
    }, false);
}(window, location));
```

That will redirect your back button to the location.replace you specify

Comment: This piece of code really helped me out. Well, for 50%. Could the same be done with the forward button? And if so, could you perhaps help me along with some example code?

Comment: This is hacky and if the user presses the back button fast and repeatedly, they will go back. At least that's from my test in Chrome.

Answer (score 12):

I think this will do the trick.
you can write your custom code to execute on browser back button click inside **onpopstate** function.
This works in HTML5.

```
 window.onpopstate = function() {
       alert("clicked back button");
    }; history.pushState({}, '');
```

Comment: This worked for me; incredibly easy solution. Saved me a ton of headaches

Answer (score 7):

I assume you wish to create a one-page application that doesn't reload the website as the user navigates, and hence you want to negate the back button's native functionality and replace it with your own. This can also be useful in mobile web-apps where using the back button inside apps is common to close an in-app window for example. To achieve this **without a library**, you need to:

**1st.** Throughout your application modify the window's `location.hash` instead of the `location.href` (which is what  tags will do by default). For example, your buttons could fire *on click* events that modify the `location.hash` like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // Prevent default behavior on <a> tags
    event.preventDefault()

    // Update how the application looks like
    someFunction()

    // Update the page's address without causing a reload
    window.location.hash = '#page2'

})
```

Do this with every button or  tag you have that would otherwise redirect to a different page and cause a reload.

**2nd.** Load this code so that you can run a function every time the page history changes (both back and forward). Instead of the switch that I used in this example, you can use an if and check for other states, even states and variables not related to `location.hash`. You can also replace any conditional altogether and just run a function every time the history changes.

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
    switch(location.hash) {
        case '#home':
            backFromHome()
            break
        case '#login':
            backFromLogin()
            break
        default:
            defaultBackAnimation()
    }
}
```

This will work until the user reaches the first page they opened from your website, then it will go back to *new tab*, or whatever website they were in before. This can't be prevented and the teams that develop browsers are patching hacks that allow this, if a user wants to exit your website by going back, they expect the browser to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a **one-page web application**, where your html body has different sections and you want to nevigate through back button to the previous section you were. This answer will help you.

Where your website sections are differentiated by #. Such as:

> *your-web-address.com/#section-name*

Just follow a few steps:

Add a class and a id in every section in you html body. Here it is ".section"

```
<section class="section" id="section-name">...</section>
```

Add two CSS class in your linked css (e.g., style.css) file to your html (e.g., index.html) file such:

```
.section .hide {
  display: none;
}
.section .active{
 dislplay: block;
}
```

Add this JavaScript function in you linked .js (e.g., main.js) file to your html file.

```
window.onpopstate = function () {
    if (location.hash !== "") {
        const hash = location.hash;
        // Deactivating existing active 'section'
        document.querySelector(".section.active").classList.add("hide");
        document.querySelector(".section.active").classList.remove("active");
        // Activating new 'section'
        document.querySelector(hash).classList.add("active");
        document.querySelector(hash).classList.remove("hide");
    }
}
```