# JavaScript: Modify last history of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How I can modify last URL of browser history ?

**Example:**

1. If currently user is on a specific page or URL, say: `/page3`
2. Because of some functionality (error handled), the user goes to `/page1`.
3. In the context of page `/page1`, if user clicks on browser's back button, I want to redirect the user to `/page2` instead of `/page3`.

How can I achieve this using JavaScript, jQuery or AngularJS?

Comment: [Location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462719/javascript-change-the-function-of-the-browsers-back-button

Answer (score 1):

in http://example.com/page3
add the few codes from the following link... this is not the exact answer... but looks like it will help you

```
function goBack() {
    window.location.hash = window.location.lasthash[window.location.lasthash.length-1];
    //blah blah blah
    window.location.lasthash.pop();
}

window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    goBack();
    history.pushState("http://example.com/page2", document.title, window.location.pathname);
//  var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
//  if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
//    evt = window.event;
//  }
//  if (evt) {
//    evt.returnValue = message;
//  }
//  return message;
  return "Back";
}
```

For more details please refer this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25806609/6082645

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008838/6082645