# State history with browser back button vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am developing an application with Vue and Laravel. Laravel is controlling my routes and I'm not using the `vue-router`.

I am conditionally loading some components based on the state of an object in my parent components data.

I have this method in my parent component:

```
  activateListingForm: function() {
    this.listingFormActive = !this.listingFormActive;
  }
```

This method is triggered by a button that will change `this.listingFormActive` to true or false.

I then have this in the template of the component:

```
  <transition name="slide-fade">
    <create-listing-form v-if="listingFormActive"></create-listing-form>
    <listings-table v-else></listings-table>
  </transition>
```

A problem that I am having is that some users are clicking the browser back button expecting the last component to load. I'm wondering if there is a way to change the state based on the back button?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is what you'd want to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462719/javascript-change-the-function-of-the-browsers-back-button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's doable. My colleagues and I had to do something similar while working on [this page](https://www.edgeprop.my/map-search-property?&state=Kuala%20Lumpur).

For it to work,

- url is the source of truth of what the value of `listingFormActive` should be
- the state of `listingFormActive` should be stored in url everytime it
  changes.
- the initial state of `listingFormActive` should be retrieved
  from url

First, watch `listingFormActive`. Everytime the state change, perform [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) to store  its state as a url query.

```
watch: {
    listingFormActive: {
        handler(v) {
            history.pushState({
                listingFormActive: v
            }, null, `${window.location.pathname}?listingFormActive=${v}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Add some utility method for getting url query

```
methods: {
    currentUrlQuery() {
        return window.location.search
            .replace("?", "")
            .split("&")
            .filter(v => v)
            .map(s => {
                s = s.replace("+", "%20");
                s = s.split("=").map(s => decodeURIComponent(s));
                return {
                    name: s[0],
                    value: s[1]
                };
            });
    },
    getListingFormActive() {
        return this.currentUrlQuery().filter(obj => obj.name === 'listingFormActive').value;
    }
}
```

the initial state of `listingFormActive` should be based on what you saved in the url

```
data() {
    return {
        listingFormActive: this.getListingFormActive() == 'true' ? true : false
    }
},
```