# Ionic 4/Angular loops in router history

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, angular2-routing, ionic4

If I navigate from one page to another and back multiple times , I am able to navigate through the whole router history via the hardware- or the browser back button.

I want to achieve that the hardware back button brings me to the same page as the `ion-back-button` in my toolbar.

**Example**

*Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 3*

I navigate from *Page 1* to *Page 2*. Then I navigate from *Page 2* to *Page 3* and back via `ion-back-button` multiple times. If I then press the hardware/browser back button, I get to *Page 2* and *Page 3* again in a loop. Instead I want the hardware/browser back button to navigate to *Page 1* if I press it on *Page 2*.

Comment: You will not get a direct method to handle browser back state. you need to handle the event and write your own code.

Comment: Here you find your answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373774/how-to-handle-back-button-on-ionic-2)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373774/how-to-handle-back-button-on-ionic-2) your find your answer that I agree withapproachproch very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed the router looping problem on Ionic 4. I am aware and previously implemented the famous back button workaround in Ionic 3, but that won't work on Ionic 4 since it uses angular routing.

So I was looking for some way to get the currently active view instance. If I get the view instance, then I can call some `backButtonAction` function defined on that page (similar to the Ionic 3 workaround).

Okay, enough chit-chat. here is the code:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChildren(IonRouterOutlet) routerOutlets:QueryList<IonRouterOutlet>;
    constructor(
    private alertCtrl:AlertController,
    private modalCtrl:ModalController,
    private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
    private menu:MenuController,
    private platform: Platform
    ){
        this.initializeApp(); 
    }

    initializeApp(){
        ...
        this.registerHardwareBackButton();  
    }

    registerHardwareBackButton() {
        this.platform.backButton.subscribe((e) => {
            e.register(999, async () => {   
            // first close any alets, modal etc. 

            const actionsheet = await this.actionSheetCtrl.getTop();             
            if(actionsheet){
                actionsheet.dismiss();
                return;             
            }

            const modal = await this.modalCtrl.getTop(); 
            if(modal){
                modal.dismiss();
                return;
            }

            const alert = await this.alertCtrl.getTop();            
            if(alert){
                alert.dismiss();
                return;             
            }

            const menu = await this.menu.getOpen();
            if(menu){
                menu.close();
                return; 
             }

             const outlet:any = this.routerOutlets.first();
             const activeView = outlet.activated.instance; // the active view instance          
             //now calls the onBackButtonPress function in that instance            
             if(activeView.onBackButtonPress){
                activeView.onBackButtonPress();                 
             }else {
                //some logic about what to do if onBackButtonPress is not defined, default action       
             }
          });
       }); 
    }
```

and if you have a user navigation flow like this HomePage => Page1 => Page2
define `onBackButtonPress` function on each like (just like the workaround for Ionic 3).

example:
on **HomePage**

```
onBackButtonPress(){
    navigator['app'].exitApp(); //closes the app, bad UX
}
```

on **Page1**

```
onBackButtonPress(){
    //back to previous page using location.back() or nav.pop()
    this.location.back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `ion-back-button` is that it doesn't use the browser's [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/History), but **navigates to a previous state** instead. That's why you noted the following behavior:

- Go back to Page 2 when clicking once on the `ion-back-button` which under the hood triggers a navigation to Page 2
- Go back to Page 3, when clicking once on the browser's back button since the previous navigation was Page 3

So what you need is your button to behave like the browser's back button.

To achieve this, forget the `ion-back-button` directive and implement the `click` behavior yourself by using [Location::back()](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#back).

Answer (score 0):

you can used this plugin 
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
This plugin makes it easy to use HTML5 style routing that web developers expect for building single-page apps.

Answer (score -2):

Basically you are trying to customize the behavior of browser back button. You can try something like below mentioned article
[Javascript : Change the function of the browser's back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462719/javascript-change-the-function-of-the-browsers-back-button)