# How to load the exact page when clicking back button on browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a search bar in my page. If I search something, My resultdiv shows me result. But when I move to next page and come back on clicking back button the resultdiv don't show my results. I want the resultdiv to be preserved. I use keyup event on my search bar.

Comment: yes, iam using PHP with jquery

Comment: you could start using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) `replaceState` to keep the last searched term in the URL. After navigating back you can fetch the data from the url... alternatively store the information in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: you are using JQuery AJAX to load search results? OR are you talking about browser's search bar?

Comment: I am loading my data from ajax

Comment: I have no experience with history api

Comment: If I'm not wrong then you must be binding AJAX response to result div, so you can use different DIV for search result list and result clicked after search item. You will have to show and hide the respective DIV on search item click and back button click to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

If you apply your search in the url bar with a question mark (known as `$_GET` in PHP) you can use the JavaScript method `window.history.go( -1 )` and this goes back to the same path before which includes the `$_GET` variable.

**URL bar:**

`my_page.php?search=something`

Comment: How do you apply your search to the page?

Comment: OP is using AJAX to load data so it will not helpful if he is loading results using ajax and binding same to result div

Comment: I want my result from keyup event to be preserved. I really need your help to tackle this.

Comment: @KalidasRajeev maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462719/javascript-change-the-function-of-the-browsers-back-button