# Change back button behaviour of browser

Tags: javascript, back

Posting without a target so that a web page reloads seems useful behaviour for some things - such as writing a login page.  I have implemented a calendar in PHP which takes advantage of this.  It reloads an object from the session (or creates a new one if not present), applying any changes that result from the post then saves the object back to the session.  The problem is this.  If I hit the back button I don't want to go back through every click of the calendar button but would rather jump back to the page before arriving at the calendar page.  Not only that, if I do go back one calendar page after another I get an annoying "confirm form resubmission".  I have implemented an incrementing value after the # for each post so that I might be able to use window.onhashchange.  The problem is that window.onhashchange never fires so I am unable to intercept the back button and pop the history stack. Any ideas?  Am I better off coding on the server side with javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript : Change the function of the browser's back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462719/javascript-change-the-function-of-the-browsers-back-button)

Comment: Maybe use the history states ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028297/js-window-history-delete-a-state

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved one problem.  My form subclass in PHP defaults to using POST as I understand this is more secure.  This causes the annoying resubmission problem when using the back button.  I now use GET in my calendar page which solves this issue.  I am still bemused by JS debugging in Netbeans.  I have never got script to stop on a breakpoint within a single document.  I have previously had it working with an external javascript source but this no longer works.  If I can output to console but there is no window in which to see the output.  I am told window.alert no longer works for some events in Chrome.  I am completely blind!  To add to the irritation, it took me a while to realize was that the javascript file was cached and changes would not be reflected in behaviour.  I have put a random number into the script tag which fixes this issue.  As I am debugging using netbeans connector in Chrome I have no idea why this does not force the js file to refresh.  All in all, this appears to be a pretty shambolic toolchain.